# Need help understanding what this function does

Tags: c++, file, header

I want to understand how this function works in C. I believe it is used to help to create a header for a file, as given by its name. This is part of a larger file that handles image processing. This part of the code, however, is after the processing is finished:

```
void header( int row, int col, unsigned char head[32] )
{
    int *p = (int *)head;
    char *ch;
    int num = row * col;

    /* Choose little-endian or big-endian header depending on the machine. Don't modify this */
    /* Little-endian for PC */

    *p = 0x956aa659;
    *(p + 3) = 0x08000000;
    *(p + 5) = 0x01000000;
    *(p + 6) = 0x0;
    *(p + 7) = 0xf8000000;

    ch = (char*)&col;
    head[7] = *ch;
    ch ++; 
    head[6] = *ch;
    ch ++;
    head[5] = *ch;
    ch ++;
    head[4] = *ch;

    ch = (char*)&row;
    head[11] = *ch;
    ch ++; 
    head[10] = *ch;
    ch ++;
    head[9] = *ch;
    ch ++;
    head[8] = *ch;

    ch = (char*)&num;
    head[19] = *ch;
    ch ++; 
    head[18] = *ch;
    ch ++;
    head[17] = *ch;
    ch ++;
    head[16] = *ch;

    /*
    // Big-endian for unix
    *p = 0x59a66a95;
    *(p + 1) = col;
    *(p + 2) = row;
    *(p + 3) = 0x8;
    *(p + 4) = num;
    *(p + 5) = 0x1;
    *(p + 6) = 0x0;
    *(p + 7) = 0xf8;
    */
}
```

Comment: Is there something in particular you want? It's populating head[] with certain values, dependent upon the initial values of row, col, and num. It uses a few magic numbers to set certain values, and rides off in the sunset.

Comment: Since it's part of an image processing, it's likely it could be reading the header of the file. Really you'd need to step through it with a debugger to see what's happening though

Answer (score 0):

Little-endian vs. big-endian refers to the way multi-byte values are stored in memory. On a little-endian machine it goes from least significant byte to most significant byte, while a big-endian machine goes in the opposite order.

The header is specified as having a big-endian order, as you can tell by the simplicity of the code in the big-endian case - each field is simply assigned directly.

For the little-endian case the bytes in each `int` must be reversed. For the constants this is easy, you just rearrange the hex values. For the integers passed to the function you must break them into 4 separate bytes and store each one individually.